# Symfony2 and Entity Field : Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "NULL" given

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have problems with my classes Symfony2.

I have 3 classes "Niveau, Classe and Serie" that here. A class is related to a level and against a Series by Series Level and are in contact with several class. Here is the source code

```
/**
 * KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\Niveau
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\NiveauRepository")
 */ 
class Niveau
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $niveau
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="niveau", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $niveau;

/**
 * @var string $code
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $code;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set niveau
 *
 * @param string $niveau
 * @return Niveau
 */
public function setNiveau($niveau)
{
    $this->niveau = $niveau;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get niveau
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNiveau()
{
    return $this->niveau;
}

/**
 * Set code
 *
 * @param string $code
 * @return Niveau
 */
public function setCode($code)
{
    $this->code = $code;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get code
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCode()
{
    return $this->code;
}
```

}

```
/**
 * KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\Serie
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\SerieRepository")
 */
class Serie
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $serie
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="serie", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $serie;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $serie
 * @return Serie
 */
public function setSerie($serie)
{
    $this->serie = $serie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSerie()
{
    return $this->seriee;
}
```

}

```
/**
 * KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\Classe
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\ClasseRepository")
 */
class Classe
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 *
 * @var type integer
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\Niveau")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $niveau;


/**
 *
 * @var type integer
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\Serie")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn
 */
private $serie;


/**
 *
 * @var type string
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\Section", inversedBy="classes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $section;




/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */ 
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set niveau
 *
 * @param KS\School\Entity\Niveau $niveau
 * @return Classe
 */
public function setNiveau(\KS\School\Entity\Niveau $niveau)
{
    $this->niveau = $niveau;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get niveau
 *
 * @return KS\School\Entity\Niveau 
 */
public function getNiveau()
{
    return $this->niveau;
}

/**
 * Set serie
 *
 * @param KS\School\Entity\Serie $serie
 * @return Classe
 */
public function setSerie(\KS\School\Entity\Serie $serie)
{
    $this->serie = $serie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get serie
 *
 * @return KS\School\Entity\Serie 
 */
public function getSerie()
{
    return $this->serie;
}

/**
 * Set section
 *
 * @param KS\School\Entity\Section $section
 * @return Classe
 */
public function setSection(\KS\School\Entity\Section $section)
{
    $this->section = $section;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get section
 *
 * @return KS\School\Entity\Section 
 */
public function getSection()
{
    return $this->section;
}


public function __toString() {
    return $this->getNiveau() . ' ' . $this->getSerie();
}
```

}

My problem is that entity in a field I want to display a dropdown that has value as a concatenation of the code level and series of Series I which procedé as follows

```
->add('class', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'KSSchoolBundle:Classe',
                    'property' => 'value',
                    'query_builder' => function (\KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\ClasseRepository $er) {
                            $results =  $er->findAllClassesByCodeAndSerie();

                            $data = array();
                            foreach ($results as $result) {
                                $data[] = array(
                                    'id' => $result['id'],
                                    'value' => $result['code'] . ' ' . is_null($result['serie']) ? '' : $result['serie'],
                                );
                            }

                            return $data;
                        },
                )
        )
```

but nothing since there. query_builder return $data that is as you see an array. id must be the value of the option tag value and value should be what the user must see, but I do not see how to do this. The browser give this error **Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given**

I wonder if that would be a way to do it right the Class class at the **__toString ()** whereby it returns something like **getNiveau (). getCode (). ''. getSerie (). getSerie ()**

Please one hand it's been two days that I am on this form.

Comment: your Niveau entity does not even have a relation to the others with dotrince. clarify and clean that up please ! i will update my answer then ...

Answer (score 1):

You return an array instead of a QueryBuilder instance in your options array for the entity field type named 'class'.

The wrong part is this one:

```
'query_builder' => function (\KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\ClasseRepository $er) {

    // this is wrong as it does not return a Query but your Class entities themself ...
    // findByCodeAndSerie would normally receive 2 arguments: $code & $serie
    // but anyway ... this does not belong here !
    $results =  $er->findAllClassesByCodeAndSerie(); 

    // ... weird stuff

    $data = array(); 

        // ... more weird stuff

    return $data;    /// you return an array instead of QueryBuilder
```

a correct implementation would be something like this:

```
use KS\SchoolBundle\Entity\ClasseRepository;

// ...
    // 'property' => 'value',       // remove this !!
    'query_builder' => function(ClasseRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.code', 'ASC');
    },
```

now just add the __toString() method to your Class entity. This will be the rendered label for the entity:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->niveau . $this->code . ' ' . $this->serie . $this->serie;
}
```

Read the [enitity field type reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) for more information and examples.